# Sorry, that page does not exist', code: 34

Tags: node.js, express, twitter

I'm working on a Node.js app that uses `statuses/show/:id` to fetch a Tweet object via its ID. However, I keep getting the following error.

"Sorry, that page does not exist', code: 34"

I've been looking for solutions, but they all usually lead back to the GET method being written incorrectly. I've double checked, though, and am pretty sure I'm writing it correctly.

```
T.get('statuses/show/:id', { id: '759043035355312128' }, function(err, data, response) {
    console.log(err);
    console.log(data);
});
```

I've also tried inputting the ID as an int, to no avail.

Comment: This code works for me. But i get "error code 34" with 'statuses/show/id' instead of 'statuses/show/:id'

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if the reference to the object is correct/ try absolute path instead of relative and see if it fixes it.

Comment: Do you mean if the ID is valid? It works when I use it in a URL, so I think so, but I might be misunderstanding what you're saying. https://twitter.com/-/status/759043035355312128